# MacBook Pro and MBox2

Tags: macbook-pro, pro-tools, mbox-2

I just upgraded from the new MacBook to the new MacBook Pro. I had a friend of mine install Pro Tools 8 HD and I'm trying to use this with my audio interface which is a mbox2, just like I was doing with my MacBook.

Apparently, this is not working because the USB light on the mbox 2 isn't coming on! Now in order to make sound come from the Pro Tools I have to manually enable an application called XVX (which I really don't know what its for besides activating the built-in output.) I'm simply trying to track a beat into pro-tools like I used to do with my MacBook but it is not letting me because my interface isn't being turned on by the MacBook Pro.

The mic lights are dimly on and when I can press the phantom power 48v light on and that will come on but the light where it says USB and spdif is not coming on at all! So how can I simply put this beat into Pro Tools...is there something internally I have to do?

Answer (score 4):

That XVX app is a crack (hardware emulator) that allows you to run the cracked version of PTHD with any hardware (even built in).  Probably not wise to be talking about the use of pirate software on a public forum :)  But since you have an Mbox, you don't even need XVX, since you should just run Protools LE.

As for your original issue, I'd suggest as Ian does, try a new cable and maybe another USB port.  Also, delete XVX, if you are running Digidesign hardware, it may be causing issues.

Answer (score 2):

XVX is known to cause issues, like any 'cracked' software.

The new MBP (i7/i5) do have issues with the USB ports when it comes to the Mbox/Mbox2.

Make sure your Mbox is connected to the port that is away from the screen (check the DUC for a response from Digi). The other port isnt Mbox friendly.

Remove the XVX app, uninstall Pro Tools (App > Digidesign > Pro Tools > Utilities) and reinstall LE with the Core Audio driver.

Comment: Just to add a little more detail, the closest USB port to you is number 1 and is a regular USB port. The one behind, or at the back, or closer to the screen, or the furthest from you... this one is hubbed with all usb devices in the laptop; keyboard, mouse, etc. I haven't had any problem with either of my ports, but some do. So try as much as possible to use the front USB port with your MBox or any high bandwidth USB device for that matter (HDDs and stuff).

Comment: Good to know about the USB issue. I was just spec-ing a new MBP i5 for work using an Mbox 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have HD on a Mac Book?

If you actually meant LE then do you have the Core Audio Driver installed? Swap out the cable you're using for another just in case there's a fault there.